# Export table to CSV in JavaScript not working for table input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, input

I have a script for exporting an output table to CSV in JavaScript. For various reasons relating to (someone else's) AJAX code, I trigger this with a link instead of a submit button.

HTML:

```html
<a href="#" class="export"><img alt="ExportToExcel" src="../export1.png"></a>
```

JavaScript:

```js
(".export").on('click', function (event) {
var d = new Date();
exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#table1'), 'export' + d.getTime() + '.csv']);
});

function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
csv=createCSV($table,"yes");
csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);
if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {     // separate deal for MS browsers
  var blob = new Blob([csv],{type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"});
  navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename + ".csv")
} else{
  $(this)
  .attr({
     'download': filename,
     'href': csvData,
     'target': '_blank'
     });
   }
}
function createCSV($table,$vis){
  if($vis==="yes"){
    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td):visible');
  }else {var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)');}
  tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11),
  tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0),
   colDelim = '","',
   rowDelim = '"\r\n"',
   csv1 = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
     var $row = $(row);
     if($vis==="yes"){$cols = $row.find('td:visible');
     }else {$cols = $row.find('td');}
     return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
       var $col = $(col),
       text = $col.text();
       return text.replace(/"/g, '""');
     }).get().join(tmpColDelim);
      }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
      .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
      .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"';
      return csv1;
   }
});
```

This all was working fine, but then I added text input fields to some rows in the table. The export leaves those blank even if data was inputted. I assume this is because I'm not resubmitting the form, but I can get the data from those fields with `('.tr_classname').serialize()`.

Comment: I haven't checked it thoroughly, but it looks like you're getting $col.text() which will only return a text node in the cell (the td). To get the text in an input, you would want to get a reference to that input itself then get the value property, with .val()

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
text = $col.text();
```

You are getting the text, but if you want to get the content of a text input, you should use

```
text = $col.val();
```

Knowing this, you have to evaluate if the content of the td is an input text or just text

Answer (score 0):

the first response was much more helpful. Thanks Mic. this worked:

replace:

```
text = $col.text();
```

with:

```
if( $col.find("input").val() != undefined){ text = $col.find("input").val();
}else { text = $col.text(); }
```